# AWS EventBridge: How to send only 1 notification when multiple objects deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I use AWS EventBridge with the following settings to activate Lambda functions. If there are three files under s3://testBucket/test/, and when these files deleted (I delete all files at the same time), EventBridge will send a notification to activate Lambda three times.

In this situation, I want to send only one notification to avoid duplicate execution of Lambda. Does anyone know how to set EventBridge to do so?

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Object Deleted"
  ],

  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": [
        "testBucket"
      ]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "test/"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

An event will be generated for each object deleted.